# Adding a search bar to Google Place Picker(GMSPlacePicker)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api, gmsautocomplete, gmsplacepicker

I am new in iOS application developer. I am using the Google place picker (`GMSPlacePicker`) and it's looking fine but not seeing searchbar. How am I supposed to add a search bar? I am referring https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/placepicker and they are providing documents on https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_ui_control but I am confused how to implement `GMSAutocompleteViewController` and `GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController` in Objective C.
Can anyone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: You can solve this issue using updated **GoogleMaps.framework**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I have just Update the **GoogleMaps.framework**.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)onLaunchClicked:(id)sender {

    if ([_textField.text length] > 0) {
        GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
        acController.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }else {
        UIAlertController *controller = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Enter a name" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

        }];
        [controller addAction:action];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

// Handle the user's selection.
- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    // Do something with the selected place.
    NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
    NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
    NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);

    [_peopleArray addObject:@{@"name":_textField.text,
                              @"place":place.name,
                              @"lat":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.6f",place.coordinate.latitude],
                              @"long":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.6f",place.coordinate.longitude]}];
    [_tableView reloadData];
    _textField.text = @"";
}

- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
didAutocompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    // TODO: handle the error.
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
}

// User canceled the operation.
- (void)wasCancelled:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment @BhavukJain